# What are these "dial gauges" called?

Tags: terminology, charts

I'm in the middle of designing a dash board, and there's somewhere where we display numbers that I really would like to have this specific type of dial gauge that I've seen before online.

[image: Image of dial guages with percentage of ring coloured]

I remember seeing an open source JavaScript library for these, can someone please remind me what these are called and where I can find them?

Comment: The JavaScript library recommendation is technically off topic, but now that you know what to search for I'm sure you can find some popular projects visualization projects that would meet your needs... [chart.js](http://www.chartjs.org/) comes to mind...

Comment: There is also knob.js http://anthonyterrien.com/knob/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming you mean the circles with the 62% and 85%...

**Doughnut Charts**

> A doughnut chart (also spelled donut) is functionally identical to a pie chart, with the exception of a blank center and the ability to support multiple statistics at once. Doughnut charts are superior to standard pie charts as they provide for a better data intensity ratio. For example, the blank center can be used to display additional, related data as shown in the example.
>
> Source: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pie_chart#Doughnut_chart)